# Web and its child webs not showing in default navigation after 2007 > 2010 upgrade

Tags: navigation, upgrade

I have a single site collection that was previously a MOSS 2007 site. This site collection has about 15 webs, and some of those have a number of subwebs underneath them. The top navigation bar is set to display all subsites, and well as the sub sites underneath them. This works without issue, and I see all root sub sites displaying, as well as their children.

After the upgrade, I have a single subsite that is not displaying in the top navigation bar. It shows in the tree control for the navigation that it is in there by default, but it does not render on the page.

What could cause I subsite navigation node not to show? I don't think it is permissions...This subsite is open to everyone. I do not see it as the Farm Account, and it is NOT hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Farm admins do not have Site Collection admin permissions. Can you confirm the subsite is not visible even after you've added yourself as Site Collection admin?

Comment: I logged in as another user account, which is a site collection admin, and it is not visible. Regular users who saw the navigation node in 2007 are the ones reporting it not to be visible in 2010.

Comment: Are these Publishing sites? Can you modify the navigation settings of the subsite in question or it's parent: just make some change, save, change it back to what it was, save?

Comment: Not publishing...I am able to modify the navigation as I wish. For example, I added a link to the site in question for temporary access. The child sites not showing are the most important part. Technically, I could manually add them, but I'm after why it/they aren't showing.

Comment: And the "show subsites" is checked in the navigation properties of the site in question? Can you try unchecking it, saving, checking it again, saving.

Is there something different with this parent site or the subsites? You've also run IISRESET several times, I assume?

Comment: Yes, show subsites is checked in the site that isn't displaying. But remember, it's not a question of the sub sites showing, this 1 specific site isn't showing at all in the navigation, so it's children isn't an issue, yet.

Answer (score 1):

Go to site settings -> Navigation. And under the "Global Navigation" option, please check the number of "Maximum number of dynamic items to show within this level of navigation:"

[image]

Try to increase it, maybe this helps. In the past i had some issue, and it was here.

Answer (score 1):

Might be long back you have asked this but future reference purpose, I had same issue couple of weeks back, turned out to be that I had more than 20 sub sites. To resolve change the default "Maximum number of dynamic items to show within this level of navigation:" to 30 on the site collection. This worked for me.

Had same issue for me. Try this. For me this was due to total no of sub sites > 20.

1. Site Settings
2. Navigation
3. Change/Set - "Maximum number of dynamic items to show within this level of navigation:" to 30 for Global Navigation and Current Navigation
4. Click OK

Hope this helps:)